# Error 0 while making ajax request to WebApi

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am making **ajax request** to my WebApi and I get the error 0 in callback once page load whereas I am geeting correct json when the url hit the WebApi.

When I inspected the page in `chrome's consol` tab shows that the url changed. I am requesting for `http://localhost:1960/api/Product/GetProducts` in my code and in chrome it changes to `http://localhost:1960/api/Product/GetProducts?_=1534696122451`.

Please suggest what should need to done.

code

```
var dataTable = $('#productTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'http://localhost:1960/api/Product/GetProducts',
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            //"success": function (result, status, xhr) {
            //    alert("Success : " + result);
            //},
            "error": function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Failed : Result: " + status + " - " + error + " | " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "productName", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "productCode", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "productDescription", "autoWidth": true },
        ],

        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No Data found, Please Click on <b><i>Add New</i></b> Button to Add Product Record in System."
        }
    });
```

also
`This is state that my client mvc project is hosted in different port.` so Is that is making problem??

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The outcome is Failed : Result: error - | 0 - error from `error` callblock @Shyju

Comment: Check the network call in browser devtools and see whether your API call is returning 200 OK or not. If not 200 OK, debug your code to see why it is not returning 200

Comment: Hi, i checked the new url, It is also omitting the result, but the full error `Failed to load http://localhost:1960/api/Product/GetProducts?_=1534701783192: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2640' is therefore not allowed access.` is still is in the mvc project. Is is because of JavaScript or Ajax request??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a security measure, browsers block any non-secure (http) request that’s not to the same origin. Here your web api is hosted on port `1960` and your web application is hosted on `2640` and that’s why you are getting this error.

You can go through this link to learn more about CORS and how to enable your API to receive CORS requests:

[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)